# Durandal view adding ".js" to filename

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I've got a Durandal 2.0 SPA which works just fine from one context but not from another. For the one that does not work the shell.html view is attempting to be loaded with using shell.html.js. Any idea why the additional .js is being added to the view file name?

Comment: please make sure you are using the text plugin to amd, which can be found here: https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/tree/master/platforms/HTML/StarterKit/lib/require

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to enable CORS on the server and then override the useXhr function in the require config per http://jaketrent.com/post/cross-domain-requirejs-text/.